# rating bar not show all star in single row

Tags: android

my rating bar not completely aline in single row see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8HwS.jpg last star will not show completely how i will fix this please help me how i will fix this to rating bar show all 5 star completely help me

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="10sp" >

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/Email"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>


   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  android:textColor="#ffffff"

    android:text="Give rating"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:rating="0" />





 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/Comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:hint="Comments"
   android:minLines="3" >
 </EditText>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Submitbtn"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Submitbtn"
        android:text="Cancel" />
   </RelativeLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If still not show complete increase few **dp**. And if shows extra star then decrease it.

Comment: you have to make changes in your dialog box layout.

Comment: finaly i did my self problem is on android:padding="10sp" at linearlayout on top i remove it now see all 5 star completely:)

Comment: if you solved it youself then post your own answer and accept it. so that others take help from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RatingBar needs a static width and you don't have it, as it wont autmatically adjust its star size, so find it a space and instead of

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:rating="0" />
```

you need

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="150dp" <!-- or whatever static size that fits-->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:rating="0" />
```

**--EDIT--**

If you want to make it smaller but not as much as @nurisezgin answer you could [style your RatingBar](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/) but you will also need the static width, another solution if you are using that layout in dialog you could set the minimum width of that dialog,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:minWidth="300dp"
 android:padding="10dp" > // also use dp for padding instead of sp
```

Comment: Consider changing your UI design, try to put your ratingBar alone in row, or at least first item to the left of row , or you need to create multiple layout files to support multiscreen http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: this code use cookie http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/  what i doin myc ode please help

Comment: use your own stars with something like 35*35 png

Comment: @Warlock you send that link in comment 10 mins before and i edit that 19 mins before.

Comment: @Warlock links are not important please try to help him. and thats the motive of all here i think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:rating="0" />
```

This decrease the width of `RatingBar`.

You can also use `Style`-

[see this link.](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/)

Comment: but my app for multiple devices with  diffrent width and height  so how can i fixed width???

Comment: Use this- @android:layout_width="fil_parent";

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh Are you just copying my solutions and edits? What's wrong with you?

Comment: i think you have to make changes in your dialog box layout.

Comment: @Warlock excuse me. you can see i answer before you and the link i've send him is different from yours.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh Have a look at timestamps again, and the link

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you set

> android:layout_width="fill_parent"

or set a static width like

> android:layout_width="300dp"

Answer (score 0):

Could you change your rating bar attrs.?
Try this attrs;

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1" />
```

Comment: is very small not usefull

Comment: You may change your dialog width. Is rating bar looks like fix in it?

Comment: Your screen have vertical space area, maybe parent layout attribute set fixed size.